# How is the strlen calculated for a string without null character?

Tags: c, string, c-strings, string-length, strlen

This code returns n=11, with 10th and 11th character as ' ' and '@'
How does this work? How does strlen function take it as 11 characters? It seems like it takes the string length as 12 characters in some compilers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void fun(char *arr)
{
   int i;
   unsigned int n = strlen(arr);
   printf("n = %d\n", n);
   for (i=0; i<n; i++)
     printf("%c  ", arr[i]);
}

int main()
{
   char arr[] = {'g', 'e', 'e', 'k', 's', 'q', 'u', 'i', 'z'};
   fun(arr);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour - anything could happen here, including seg fault or non termination.

Comment: You happen to have a nul character in memory somewhere after the end of the "geeksquiz" constant. There may be some logic to it given other values you're going to have in a read-only data segment (nothing springs to mind) but it's definitely not something you should rely on.

Comment: "a string without null character" **is not a string**

Answer (score 10):

According to standard, since your "string" does not have null terminator, this is not a string. Calling `strlen` with anything but string is undefined behavior, so anything can happen including the case you're observing.

If you wonder, how exactly this is happening, this is likely because of `strlen` keeps trying to find null terminator, and occasionally finds it in memory somewhere after the `arr`.

Note that this code can even segfault, if null terminator will not be found "fast enough".

You can use tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html) to detect such memory access violations.

Answer (score 3):

In `C`, a "string" has a `NUL` character at the end. A `char[]` without `NUL` is just a `char[]` not a "string".

Arrays in `C` don't have their length stored anywhere, so `strlen()` goes as long as `NUL` hasn't been found. You were probably lucky to have `NUL` right few memory cells after array ended.

Comment: `NUL` and `NULL` are not the same. `NUL`, `'\0'`, `0` and "null character"  are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you initialize string, the compiler adds `nul` operator `\0` automatically for you. For example,like what you are trying to do in your code is just making the char array, instead of doing this you can use, `" "` and compiler will automatically add the `\0` for you same case when you ask input for string from users. But certainly there are cases when you need to add the `nul` operator by yourself, example, when you are trying to break the character string word by word and try to save them in array of pointers , syntax : `char *str[20]` then you have to have add `\0` at the end. And If you are not happy with `strlen()` function, you can code your own like this :

```
size_t count = 0;
while (str != '\0'){     //str is the string name
count++;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: There is no such thing as a "*`nul` operator*" in C. You probably meant the `0`-terminator, aka null-terminator, aka `NUL`-terminator.

Comment: I suggest you to open and revise book again. There is `NULL` which is for pointer, value assign by compiler to global pointer , for local pointer you need to assign that for yourself, and there is `nul` terminator which is the part of string, if you open your book and read the strings, then you will know what this term and sign `\0` called. Well thanks for and yeah, `0` is the digit , its not any terminator. @alk

Comment: `NUL` is the name for the character with the value `'\0'` which is equal to the value `0`. It is used to terminate a C-"string". Those have *nothing* to do with the null-pointer value `NULL`, at least not in C. Mind the different number and capitalisation of the various `L/l`s. I recommend the C Standard here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html

Comment: Thanks, I guess I am the one who needs to read more, thanks for the link @alk